# Changing "identity" of Azure users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm in the process of migrating my Azure portal registration from one login email (which will be going away) to another.

Originally I registered with a user under the `kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com` domain which came from a Microsoft Exchange Online plan, and which will be going away soon.

I don't want to lose the OAUTH2 app registrations on the Azure portal when that happens, so I added a domain which I own (`sugarmail.app`) and a user under that domain (`admin@sugarmail.cpp`) with a Global Administrator role.

So far so good.

Now my question.

The identity of the new user, `admin@sugarmail.com` is showing as `kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com` (old domain which will be going away) - is that something to worry about?

[image: users]

I suppose that's some sort of "default identity provider" for my Azure portal registration? I'm a bit nervous that when my Exchange Online subscription expires, and with it the `kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com` domain expires too, then the new user will be somehow affected.

Is there any way to edit the "identity" either of that existing user, or create a new identity (under the new domain) and use it when creating yet another new user?

For reference, here are my Domains settings, the new domain is there and is set as default (primary):

[image: domains]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to confirm that kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com is default/initial domain assigned when you created Azure AD. The identities section on all users blade always reflect default/initial domain.

- You would not loose kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com even when your Exchange license expired.
- The initial domain remains valid until the tenant is active.
- The reason identity for new users from verified domain also shows up as kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com is since the portal is designed to reflect the initial domain name of the tenant which user belongs to. Hence even if you add a new domain and create user with that domain Azure Portal would still reflect Identities section as kmansoft.onmicrosoft.com.
- There is no way to edit Identities section of user on Azure AD >> All Users blade.
- Identities section on Azure AD >> All Users blade is by default defined by Azure AD and contain one of following "Initial/Default Domain name or ExternalAzureAD"